# My question was put on hold. I rephrased it. Can I get it unlocked?

Tags: support, specific-question, reopen-closed

The question in... question: [Can 'ssh <host> <command>' be configured to always load server-side startup files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192486/can-ssh-host-command-be-configured-to-always-load-server-side-startup-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been reopened. You can just flag for mod attention next time (the "flag" link under the post).

Comment: oh, sorry didn't realize that.  thank you!